# Drawing polyline that grows as the car moves by taking data from MySql and PHP in Google API

Tags: google-maps, php, mysql, google-maps-api

I wanted to show the polyline on google Map as car moves with animation (like in this site: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm) by taking data from MySQL and PHP. For that i refered the code from Google API  tutorial [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines). I have also taken data for this from my SQL which is as follow:
.html

```
function load() {
    var point;
                    var flightPlanCoordinates=new Array();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.33, 73.55),
                zoom: 7,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                 },
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            });

            downloadUrl("xmltry.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;

        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon")));
            flightPlanCoordinates[i]=point;
          }
          var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);

      });

        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
    function doNothing() {}
```

.php file:

```
<?php
//require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
include 'common_db.inc';
// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT  `lat`, `lon` FROM current_location Where Device_ID='HGS1005'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lon", $row['lon']);  
  } 

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

But now i wanted to show polyline with animation as show in [1st](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm) references site.Can any one suggest me some references or help me out in same. 
I am getting this result which is correct but want animation in it as in http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm
[image]
Hope this time my title and description part is understood.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Maps Javascript API docs for Polyline (note the `path` property)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline):

> The ordered sequence of coordinates of the Polyline. This path may be
>   specified using either a simple array of LatLngs, or an MVCArray of
>   LatLngs. Note that if you pass a simple array, it will be converted to
>   an MVCArray **Inserting or removing LatLngs in the MVCArray will
>   automatically update the polyline on the map**.

Knowing that, I'd try it like this:

```
// I assume you've got your GPS signal pumping updates to your client.
// Insert a new GPS point into your Polyline's point array.
function OnGpsPulse(newLat, newLon)
{
  // Insert a new point at the end of the LatLng Array.
  pointIndex = flightPlanCoordinates.length;      
  flightPlanCoordinates[pointIndex]=new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLon);

  // And the line should automatically update in the map.
}
```

As an afterthought, each GPS pulse should be dispatching an event that you may need/want to handle in two places. First, if you want to store vehicles' positions indefinitely, you'll need to collect them server-side and push them into your database. However, if you just want a vehicle to draw a line while it travels, you can keep that functionality in the client.

Comment: Thanks for reply but, i will have data store in my database i.e.MySQL. I don't want live tracking but history of where my vehicle  has moved, for that i wanted to show animation of track as in this example (http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm). I wanted to add animation to stored data. where car image(i.e. png) will move and vehicle track will draw as this image move as in first link.